Reducing Estimator time for calculating expectation values
I have a circuit with $2N + 1$ qubits and with depth $2t + 2$, where $t$ is essentially the number of trotter steps, or the number of times a fixed block of gates repeats itself in the circuit. After running this circuit for $N=10$, and $t = 5$, I find that using Estimator to calculate $\langle Z \rangle$ acting on the middle qubit ($q_N$ in this case) takes around $\approx 6$ mins. Problem is, I wish to do this for all $0 \leq t \leq 100$, but even up to $t=5$, this takes around 26 mins, which is very long. I have attached a picture of the circuit below for $t=2$:
$N=10, t = 2$" />
Is there any way to reduce the time taken by the Estimator to calculate the expectation values, or is it not possible at all? Should I be using any other method for this? The $fsim(\theta,\phi)$ gate is just $e^{i\theta (XX + YY)}$, although I have passed it as a $4 \times 4$ matrix using the Operator class and then passed it onto the circuit with the unitary method. The $U(\theta_k, \theta_z)$ is also an $8 \times 8$ Unitary matrix, passed using Operator class again (I haven't decomposed any of these into fundamental one or two-qubit gates, does that heavily affect the performance?). I used Qiskit-aer's primitive Estimator with approximation = True and shots = None for exact Expectation values.
Edit: I am also attaching the code block used to create the circuit down below. I also use a different function called fermi_state_circuit() to initialize my circuit with. Here, the code uses ts_state_circuit():
def ts_state_circuit(N, num_cl_bits = 0):  #Initialize state with fixed number of paricles in up or down chain
    qc = QuantumCircuit(2*N+1,num_cl_bits)
    str1 = ''
    str2 = ''
    for i in range(N):
        if i%2 == 0:
            str1 += '1'
            str2 += '0'
        else:
            str1 += '0'
            str2 += '1'
    state = (Statevector.from_label(str1) + Statevector.from_label(str2))/np.sqrt(2)
    qc.initialize(state,range(N))
    qc.initialize(state,range(N+1,2*N+1))
    return qc




    
def kondo_unitary(theta_k,theta_z):

    l1 = cm.exp(1j*theta_z/2)
    l2 = cm.exp(-1j*theta_z/2)
    c1 = m.cos(theta_k)
    s1 = m.sin(theta_k)

    a = m.cos(np.sqrt(2)*theta_k) - (1j/np.sqrt(2))*m.sin(np.sqrt(2)*theta_k)
    a_dag = m.cos(np.sqrt(2)*theta_k) + (1j/np.sqrt(2))*m.sin(np.sqrt(2)*theta_k)
    b = (-1j/np.sqrt(2))*m.sin(np.sqrt(2)*theta_k)
    c = cm.exp(-1j*theta_k) 
    d = cm.exp(1j*theta_k)

    """kondo_unitary = Operator([[1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
                          [0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0],
                          [0,0,l1,0,0,0,0,0],
                          [0,0,0,c1*l2,1j*l2*s1,0,0,0],
                          [0,0,0,1j*l2*s1,c1*l2,0,0,0],
                          [0,0,0,0,0,l1,0,0],
                          [0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0],
                          [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1]])"""
    kondo_unitary = Operator([[1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
                          [0,a,0,0,0,0,b,0],
                          [0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0],
                          [0,0,0,d,0,0,0,0],
                          [0,0,0,0,c,0,0,0],
                          [0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0],
                          [0,b,0,0,0,0,a_dag,0],
                          [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1]])
    
    kondo_unitary_2 = Operator([[1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
                          [0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0],
                          [0,0,c1*l1,0,0,1j*s1*l1,0,0],
                          [0,0,0,l2,0,0,0,0],
                          [0,0,0,0,l2,0,0,0],
                          [0,0,1j*s1*l1,0,0,c1*l1,0,0],
                          [0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0],
                          [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1]])
    
    return kondo_unitary_2

def circuit_3(N, trotter_steps,angles = 0,theta_k = 0,theta_z = 0, num_cl_bits = 0, trotter_barriers = False, save = False):
    if num_cl_bits == 0:
        qc = ts_state_circuit(N)
    else:
        qc = ts_state_circuit(N,num_cl_bits)
    qc.x(N)
    qc.barrier()
    
    c = num_qubits//2
    if trotter_steps == 0:
        if save == True:
            qc.save_statevector()
        return qc
    else:
        add_fsim_half(qc,angles)
        qc.unitary(kondo_unitary(theta_k,theta_z),[c,c+1,c-1],label=r'$U_{k}(\theta_k,\theta_z)$')
    
   
        if trotter_barriers:
                qc.barrier()
        for i in range(1,trotter_steps):
            add_fsim_full(qc,angles)
            qc.unitary(kondo_unitary(theta_k,theta_z),[c,c+1,c-1],label=r'$U_{k}(\theta_k,\theta_z)$')
        
            if trotter_barriers:
                qc.barrier()
        add_fsim_inv_half(qc,angles)
        if save == True:
            qc.save_statevector()
        #qc.save_statevector()  remove save for changing to operator
        return qc


    

def plot_mag_impurity(qc,index,sz_list1):
    imp_observables = SparsePauliOp('I'*N + 'Z' + 'I'*N)
    job_1 = estimator.run(qc,imp_observables,shots = None)
    sz_list1.append((job_1.result().values[0],index))
    #
    # print("Value appended to list",job_1.result().values[0])



###################    Step 4: The main code which generates <S^z-imp>, <H>(t) and entanglement measures w.r.t time and space    ###########################
print(f"Sz results for N = {N}, and t = {max_trotter_steps} and TS State")

measured_bits =list(range(2*N + 1))  #list of qubits to measure

pos_list = list(range(N) ) #list of positions to calculate correlator functions

estimator = Estimator(approximation=True) #estimator object to estimate the expectation values
sampler = Sampler()  #sampler object to sample the circuits

sz_list1 = []


if theta_k > theta:
    print('Kondo interaction is greater than hopping parameter. Skipping over values')
else:
    print('Creating super list of circuits....')

    t0 = time.time()
    theta_z = -theta_k
    qc_list = [0]*max_trotter_steps
    qc_list2 = [0]*max_trotter_steps

    t0 = time.time()
    theta_z = -theta_k
    
    qc_list2[0] = circuit_3(N, 0, theta,theta_k,theta_z)
    qc_list[0] = qc_list2[0].copy()
    c = num_qubits//2
    for t in range(1,max_trotter_steps):
        #print("Value of t:", t)
        qc = qc_list2[t-1].copy()
        if t == 1:
            add_fsim_half(qc,theta)
            qc.unitary(kondo_unitary(theta_k,theta_z),[c,c+1,c-1],label=r'$U_{k}(\theta_k,\theta_z)$')
        else:
            add_fsim_full(qc,theta)
            qc.unitary(kondo_unitary(theta_k,theta_z),[c,c+1,c-1],label=r'$U_{k}(\theta_k,\theta_z)$')
        qc.barrier()

                
                #qc.measure(measured_bits,list(range(len(measured_bits))))

            
        #print("QC DEpth for list2:",qc.depth())   
        qc_list2[t] = qc.copy()
        #print(qc_list2[t].depth())
        add_fsim_inv_half(qc,theta)
        #print("QC DEpth for list1:",qc.depth())   
        qc_list[t] = qc.copy()
        #print(qc_list[t].depth())
        del qc

    t1 = time.time()

    total1 = t1-t0

I am also attaching the code for fermi_state_circuit():
coeff_dict  = {}

def array_k1(num_qubits):  #assuming num_qubits is even
    array_k = []
    m = num_qubits/2
    if (m)%2!=0: #replace with m-1 for previous results
        for j in range(-int((m)//2),int((m)//2) + 1): #replace with m-1 for previous results
            array_k.append(2*np.pi*j/num_qubits)
    else:
        for j in range(-int((m)//2),int((m)//2)):
            array_k.append(2*np.pi*j/num_qubits)
    return array_k


def recursive_nested(l,num_qubits,coeff_array,coeff = 1,bitstr=''):

    m = int(num_qubits/2) # taking always even number of qubits

    #coeff_dict_2 = {}
    if l==m-1: # m-1, but we start with 0 indexing
        coeff_copy = coeff  #to ensure multiplied coeffs in previous rounds is preserved and reused
        bitstr_copy = bitstr
        for i in range(num_qubits):
            if str(i) in bitstr:
                pass
            else:
                coeff = coeff*coeff_array[l,i]
                bitstr = bitstr + f'{i}'
                bitstr_sorted = sort_bitstr(bitstr) #to sort the string first
                perm = perm_str2(bitstr,bitstr_sorted) # to compare hamming distance
                if bitstr_sorted in coeff_dict.keys():
                    coeff_dict[bitstr_sorted]+=coeff*perm
                else:
                    coeff_dict[bitstr_sorted] = coeff*perm
            bitstr = bitstr_copy
            coeff = coeff_copy
    if l!=m-1:
        coeff_copy = coeff  #to ensure multiplied coeffs in previous rounds is preserved and reused
        bitstr_copy = bitstr
        for i in range(num_qubits):
            if str(i) in bitstr:
                pass
            else:
                #print(coeff)
                coeff = coeff*coeff_array[l,i]
                bitstr += str(i)
                recursive_nested(l+1,num_qubits,coeff_array,coeff,bitstr)
            bitstr = bitstr_copy
            coeff = coeff_copy

    return coeff_dict

def sort_bitstr(bitstr):
    bit_array = []
    for i in bitstr:
        bit_array.append(i)
    #print(bit_array)
    bitstr_sorted = ''
    for i in range(len(bit_array)):
        bit_array[i] = int(bit_array[i])
    bit_array.sort()
    #print(bit_array)
    for i in bit_array:
        #print(i,str(i))
        bitstr_sorted += str(i)
        #print(bitstr_sorted)

    return bitstr_sorted

def perm_str2(cmpr,word):

   #  word = 'eyssaasse' base string
   # cmpr = 'seasysaes'  a string to find number of swaps from the base string
    swaps = 0

    # 1)
    chars = {c: [] for c in word}
    [chars[c].append(i) for i, c in enumerate(word)]
    for k in chars.keys():
        chars[k] = cycle(chars[k])

    # 2)
    idxs = [next(chars[c]) for c in cmpr]

    # 3)
    for cmb in combinations(idxs, 2):
        if cmb[0] > cmb[1]:
            swaps += 1

    #print(swaps)
    if swaps%2 == 0:
        return 1
    else:
        return -1
    
def fermi_state(num_qubits): #of the form num_qubits = 2*odd number. This function created the fermi state (FS)


    coeff_dict.clear()
    m = int(num_qubits/2)
    coeff_array = []
    array_k = array_k1(num_qubits)
    for k in array_k:
        pos_list = []
        for x in range(num_qubits):
            pos_list.append(np.exp(-1j*k*x))
        coeff_array.append(pos_list)

    coeff_array = np.array(coeff_array)

    #print(coeff_array)

    coeff_dict_2 = recursive_nested(0,num_qubits,coeff_array)
    #print(coeff_dict_2)
    bitstr_dict = {}
    for bstr in coeff_dict_2.keys():
        vac_str = ''
        num_list = []
        for k in range(m):
            num_list.append(int(bstr[k]))

        for i in range(num_qubits):
            if i in num_list:
                vac_str += '1'
            else:
                vac_str += '0'
        bitstr_dict[vac_str] = coeff_dict[bstr]

    #print(bitstr_dict)
    

    fermi_state = Statevector([0]*(2**num_qubits))

    for bstr in bitstr_dict.keys():
        fermi_state += Statevector.from_label(bstr)*bitstr_dict[bstr]

    val_array = []
    for i in bitstr_dict.values():
        val_array.append(i)
    np_array = np.array(val_array)
    #print(np_array)
    #print(np.linalg.norm(np_array))
    
    fermi_state = fermi_state/np.linalg.norm(val_array)
    #print(fermi_state)
    fermi_state.is_valid()

    return fermi_state

def fermi_state_circuit(N,num_cl_bits = 0):  #Initialize circuit with FS with both spin chains having it's own FS
    qc = QuantumCircuit(num_qubits,num_cl_bits)
    fermi_state_up = fermi_state(N)
    fermi_state_down = fermi_state(N)
    qc.initialize(fermi_state_up,range(N))
    qc.initialize(fermi_state_down,range(N+1,2*N+1))
    return qc


Just to be sure, you're using a simulator for that right, not a real quantum machine?

@Tristan Nemoz Yes, I use the Estimator from qiskit_aer.primitives with approximation = True and shots = None

Can you share the code you're using to create this circuit?

@TristanNemoz I have added the code now. It might be a bit difficult to read unfortunately
